# Alignment of ng-repeat elements using bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal window using twitter bootstrap, i need to align certain elements inside a tab, i have followed the documentation and did several changes, it dint help. Is there any bootstrap expert to help me on this?.Here is my problem.

**Html:**

```
<tab heading="Series">
                    <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group row"  ng-repeat="ser in chartSeries">
                                    <ul class="liInline">
                                    <li class="row-fluid">Title <input ng-model="ser.name"></li>
                                    <li class="row-fluid">Type <select ng-model="ser.type" ng-options="t.id as t.title for t in chartTypes"></select></li>
                                    <li class="row-fluid">Color <input ng-model="ser.color"></li>
                                    <li class="row-fluid">Width <input ng-model="ser.lineWidth"></li>
                                    <li class="row-fluid">Dash Style <select ng-model="ser.dashStyle" ng-options="ds.id as ds.title for ds in dashStyles"></select></li>
                                    <li class="row-fluid"><label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="ser.connectNulls"> interpolate</label></li>
                                    <li class="row-fluid"><button ng-click="removeSeries($index)">Delete</button></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                    </div>
                 </tab>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Why are you using LI elements, no labels and classes that don't match. Just look at the documentation on Bootstrap and follow that, here's an example -> http://jsfiddle.net/LeBen/kY5LL/156/

Comment: @adeneo could you provide a sample that matches my requirement?

Comment: I'm not very good with either Angular nor Bootstrap, so it would probably take me longer to figure out than it would for you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you need but

For this class

```
class="form-group row"
```

Add a width like 1280px or so for example

and on the

```
<li class="row-fluid">
```

add a float left

a jsfiddle of it the above  http://jsfiddle.net/Lgxzzrfy/1/